# How to get if whoid belongs to task in a salesforce flow?

Tags: visual-workflow, standard-objects

I am trying to update a field in lead when a new task is inserted. How do I find out if the `whoid` associated with a task belongs to a lead?

I know we can write an apex invocable action and do it. Is there any other way to find out without writing code.

Comment: Does the `{variable}.{polymorphic field}:{SObject name}.{field}` syntax outlined in [this help article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_forcecom_flow_polymorphic.htm&type=5&release=202) do anything for you?

Comment: @DerekF - i will try and let you know